# How to filter out matches between arrays, and add an additional key/value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays that contain objects. Each object has a key/value pair of "color" and "number". I want to check against these 2 arrays to find the objects that match the "number". After finding this, I want to add a key value pair to all the objects in the original array.

I have the below example which I believe is on the right track, but am struggling to find out how to proceed.

Basically, if the object matches, I want to change the K/V pair of "match" to either true or false.

```
const array1 = [ {color: 'red', number: 1, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 2, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''} ]
const array2 = [ {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 5, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 6, match: ''} ]

async function findMatchingObjects(array1, array2){
    const matchCheck = array1.filter(matchedObj => array2.includes(matchedObj));
  console.log(matchCheck);
}

findMatchingObjects(array1, array2);
```

expected output would be:

```
const array3 = [{
  color: 'red',
  number: 1,
  match: 'false'
}, {
  color: 'red',
  number: 2,
  match: 'false'
}, {
  color: 'red',
  number: 3,
  match: 'true'
},
{
  color: 'red',
  number: 3,
  match: 'true'
}, {
  color: 'blue',
  number: 5,
  match: 'false'
}, {
  color: 'blue',
  number: 6,
  match: 'false'
}]
```

Comment: expected output ?

Comment: @CodeManiac added

Comment: Why your function is declared as `async`? there are no `async` operations in there

Comment: @gbalduzzi the arrays are coming from a promise in my full code

Comment: you should use `array1.reduce()`. and inside of the reducer you can perform another loop on `array2`, compare the values and make the changes to `array1`'s objects as needed to output what you want in `array3`. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: you really want `{color: 'red', number: 3, match: true }` to appear twice in the result?

Comment: @user633183 I'm basically trying to build an array that lists out whether array 2 matches on array 1. The K/V pairs may be different, because I would only want to check if the `number` value matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `some`

Here idea is

- First merge both the array's in a temp varibale.
- Get the length of first array in a variable.
- Now map on merged array and for each index less than `length1` match it with `array2` else match it with `array1`

```js
const array1 = [ {color: 'red', number: 1, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 2, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''} ]
const array2 = [ {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 5, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 6, match: ''} ]

let temp = [...array1,...array2]
let length1 = array1.length
let op = temp.map((inp,index)=> ({...inp, match: (index < length1 ?array2 : array1).some(({number})=> number === inp.number)}))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of reusability, would this work if only `number` matched? That's why I was originally looking into a `filter`

Comment: @knockedloose what do you mean by `would this work if only number matched? ` if no number matches it will simply put match as false

Comment: If arr1 had an object `{color: 'red', number: 1, match: ''}` where as arr2 had `{color: 'blue', number: 1, match: ''}`. Would that get picked up as a match, or is it looking to match the entire object?

Comment: @knockedloose it will match as we are just matching based on number not based on name. this is what you specified in question. you can use `name && number` if you want both of them must match case

Comment: Ah, understandable, this really clean and concise, thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: @knockedloose always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think in another way besides checking array1 in array2 and vice-versa. Concating these two arrays before can handle false positives.

```js
const array1 = [ {color: 'red', number: 1, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 2, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''} ]
const array2 = [ {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 5, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 6, match: ''} ]

function checkMatchesByNumbers(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.map(x => (arr2.filter(y => y.number === x.number).length > 0 ? x.match = true : x.match = false, x));
}

let resp = [].concat(checkMatchesByNumbers(array1, array2), checkMatchesByNumbers(array2, array1));

console.log(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want to preserve the duplicates, as in your provided expected output, that's how I would do it:

```js
let t = [...array1, ....array2]
return t.map(item => {
  item.match = t.filter(i => { i.number === item.number }).length > 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and `find()`

```js
const array1 = [ {color: 'red', number: 1, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 2, match: ''}, {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''} ]
const array2 = [ {color: 'red', number: 3, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 5, match: ''}, {color: 'blue', number: 6, match: ''} ]


function checkMatches(arr1,arr2){
 return arr1.map(x => arr2.find(a => a.number === x.number) ? ({...x,match:'true'}) : ({...x,match:'false'}));
}
let res = [...checkMatches(array1,array2),...checkMatches(array2,array1)]

console.log(res)
```